# Usar Function para cargar un dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio, function

Me gustaría saber como usar Function() para cargar un data.frame
Por ejemplo:

```
mi_df <- data.frame(
  "entero" = 1:4, 
  "factor" = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), 
  "numero" = c(1.2, 3.4, 4.5, 5.6),
  "cadena" = as.character(c("a", "b", "c", "d"))
)
```

No se si seria algo como:

```
 mi_df <- function(x) {
 mi_df <- data.frame(
      "entero" = 1:4, 
      "factor" = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), 
      "numero" = c(1.2, 3.4, 4.5, 5.6),
      "cadena" = as.character(c("a", "b", "c", "d"))
    )
```

Con el fin de poder usar esta función cada vez que la necesite
Muchas gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los objetos creados dentro de una función, son locales, para usarlos fuera de la misma, necesitarás retornar  el objeto, en este caso el `data.frame` creado, es decir:

```
mi_df <- function(x) {
  mi_df <- data.frame(
    "entero" = 1:4, 
    "factor" = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), 
    "numero" = c(1.2, 3.4, 4.5, 5.6),
    "cadena" = as.character(c("a", "b", "c", "d"))
  )
  return(mi_df) 
}
```

Puedes usar `return(mi_df)`  o incluso, simplemente colocar como última instrucción, el nombre del objeto a retornar `mi_df`, luego simplemente para usarlo:

```
df <- mi_df()
df

  entero factor numero cadena
1      1      a    1.2      a
2      2      b    3.4      b
3      3      c    4.5      c
4      4      d    5.6      d
```

Comentario aparte, en las versiones de R anteriores a la 4, las columnas tipo caracter se transforman por defecto en `factor`, a partir de la v4 esto cambió. Para hacer consistente los nombres de columnas con el tipo de factor incluso entre versiones, te sugiero el uso explicito de `stringsAsFactors`,  algo así:

```
mi_df <- function(x) {
  mi_df <- data.frame(
    "entero" = 1:4, 
    "factor" = factor(c("a", "b", "c", "d")), 
    "numero" = c(1.2, 3.4, 4.5, 5.6),
    "cadena" = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
  return(mi_df) 
}
```

Comment: Como siempre muchísimas gracias; Patricio